# Error about “A single query's result set can't execeed 2 billion rows”

Tags: performance, dolphindb

I run the script in DolphinDB GUI, and get the error as below:

```py
A single query's result set can't execeed 2 billion rows
```

Is there a parameter to let go of this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, the restrictions are not released. The number of queries can be reduced for parallel queries.